# How to set the results in MultiAutoCompleteTextView to be from web source instead of static or DB results?

Tags: android, android-widget, autocompletetextview

I have an app with MultiAutoCompleteTextView and I need to set the reuslts to be from a web source JSON/XML or any format how can I perform that, or to be more clear what do I need to change when I create my own custom Adapter for the autocmplete ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a way to do it here it is:

This is my layout:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the main activity, It's an example of getting skills from linkedin JSON

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public MultiAutoCompleteTextView MultiAutocomplete1;
    public String data;
    public List<String> suggest;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
        // multiAutoCompleteTextView1
        MultiAutocomplete1 = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);


        // MultiAutocomplete1.setAdapter(adapter);
        MultiAutocomplete1
                .setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

        MultiAutocomplete1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                String newText = s.toString();
                String[] parts = newText.split(",");
                if(parts[parts.length -1].length() > 1){                    
                    new getJson().execute( parts[parts.length -1] );
                }
            }

        });

        // button1
        final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        String.valueOf("Your Input : "
                                + MultiAutocomplete1.getText().toString()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class getJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... key) {
            String newText = key[0];
            newText = newText.trim();
            newText = newText.replace(" ", "+");
            try {
                HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet("http://www.linkedin.com/ta/skill?query="+newText);

                ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);
                suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jobj.getJSONArray("resultList");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    String SuggestKey = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("displayName");
                    suggest.add(SuggestKey);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                            suggest);
                    MultiAutocomplete1.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea on the split function. Thank you. ^^

Comment: I have same requirement.I need to show the drop down after getting server response.But it is not displayed.Can you help me.

Comment: Hi Shehabix, Thankyou very much.Yourcode working sucessfully. i have doubt how to change the dropdownlist background and text color.