# Android MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocomplete

I need to show the list of friends when the user types a letter in Edittext like Twitter.I have tried with MultiAutoCompleteTextView and it works fine if the arraylist is loaded before user starts entering.But I need to make a server call to get the friends having the name starts with the types character.But after getting the api response the dropdown is not showing.How can I implement this.Please help me.

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191804/how-to-set-the-results-in-multiautocompletetextview-to-be-from-web-source-instea) about the same problem. try that way. cheers!

Comment: @Dinithed Thank you.But not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [psknik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16670753/1767260).Solution is

```
CharSequence constraint = actv.getText();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint);
        actv.showDropDown();
```